# How to keep docker containers running when they are installed with ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, supervisord

I've been using ansible [docker module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_module.html) to install several containers on a server. I have containers with services running on them, like mysql or mongodb.

But sometimes my containers stop running, so I have to run the playbook again in order to get them running back again.

I've been trying to use supervisord and writing the docker command to run the containers in supervisor configuration. But by doing this, there is no need to use ansible docker module. And I'd love to continue using it since it makes docker configuration cleaner and less tedious.

Is there a better way to achieve this using ansible docker module? What's the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`docker` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_module.html) has a `restart_policy` option, which translates to the [`--restart` parameter of the docker command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart).

You get the desired behavior by applying this to your task:

```
restart_policy: on-failure
```

Comment: That was quick!. Thanks!